# Поиск топикстартер на vk.com

Tags: vkontakte-api

В контакте уже не раз видел записи на стенах, которые много раз поститили-перепостили, прям как [письмо счастья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F).
Ну? например про расформировании питомника.
Вот и возник вопрос: **можно ли средствами vkontakte-api найти топик-стартер и страничку автора?**

Comment: исправьте забавный «посик» на «Поиск», пожалуйста : )

Comment: http://ru.fishki.net/picsw/042012/19/pics/pics-090.jpg

Comment: зачем? пусть посик у саппорта ВК спросит.. так лучше знают =)

Comment: Кажется с помощью wall.get можно, но не уверен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, пожалуй. Метод [wall.getbyId()](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.getById) возвращает поля `copy_owner_id` и `copy_post_id` — у какого пользователя была скопирована именно эта запись.
Далее рекурсия, пока эти два поля не окажутся пустыми: оригинал!

Comment: Если сделать перепост с перепоста, то в качестве owner_id будет выступать по-прежнему id оригинального автора (а не того, у кого конкретно вы сделали перепост) - разве не так? Тогда "рекурсия" там незачем.

Comment: Не проверял. Как дойдут руки - отпишусь (нескоро)